# Executing a CD command in Cygwin from a BAT/CMD file

Tags: cygwin, cmd, batch-file

I need to write a bat/cmd script that executes a few applications sequentially after I have ran a node.JS socket server. I am doing this using Cygwin. I think the problem is/what I can't get my head around is waiting for Cygwin to login before executing a command.

So is there any way to listen for the login to be complete. Before entering commands to cygwin?

bash --login -i

any pointers will be appreciated.

thanks Jono

Comment: Please explain "listen for the login to complete." What login are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/
Cygwin is not for such kind of work.

Gnuwin32 is native port of GNU UNIX coreutils and more. 
They are native and live in cmd.exe.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what the OP is trying to do (and he hasn't responded to a request for clarification), but whatever it is Cygwin should be able to do it.  You can invoke Cygwin commands from native Windows bat/cmd files, and vice versa.  You just have to be careful about paths.